# MySQL query comparing NOW() with ISO string

Tags: mysql

I would like some confirmation on how NOW function works in MySQL

According to the docs and when runing the this query `SELECT NOW()` the mysql returns the current time (local time i guess?) in following format `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`.

If this is the case, then how come this works when comparing NOW() to a column that includes a UTC ISO date and time?

For example this works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM table where deadline > NOW() # deadline column contains a utc ISO string
```

Is the query above reliable or did it just return the correct answer by luck?

in case this is NOT reliable, how would you do the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL `NOW()`-function returns a datetime in the session timezone. MySQL has `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`-function which returns current UTC date and time, which will work better when you are compare it to an UTC date time.

Note that you should store datetimes as DATETIME, instead of char/varchar (assume this is what you meant by "UTC ISO date and time").

Comment: i rather save date and time as ISO string (eg 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z) if it work good when comparing to UTC_TIMESTAMP or NOW

Comment: MySQL has DATETIME and TIMESTAMP datypes for this. By using native datatypes you not only avoid conversion from datatype from another (char -> timestamp) but also other benefits (validity checking, better performance, make your code less error prone etc). So, it is not a good choise to use chars for datetime. You can always get the ISO string from native datatype if you need it. Comparing `NOW()` with datetime in UTC ISO string will not work as NOW() is in session timezone and the UTC part is ignored in the comparision.

Comment: Yes i agree that Comparing NOW() with datetime in UTC should not work but somehow it works, even when printing NOW() alone returns time in different timezone than UTC, that why i was wondering if MySQL is recognizing that and is doing some magic in the background. because i did test it multiple times and it worked down to mintues :S

Comment: It will work only if your session timezone is set to UTC. If you want to store the datetimes as text, it is your choise. It is just bad bad practice and your system will be error-prone.